# react - Add a component after main component has loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a functional react component like this:

```
function ComponentA(){
 function AddComponentB(){
  return <><ComponentB /></>
 }
  useEffect(() => {
    AddComponentB();
  }, []);
 return 
  <>
   <div id="parent"></div>
  </>
}
```

Now I have understood that everything under `useEffect` is loaded once the `ComponentA` is loaded. I want to add the `ComponentB` to div with id `parent`. Please help me understand how do I specify where to add the component.

P.S. I know I can do it by `document.getElementById("parent").append(ComponentB)` but I am looking for other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not manipulate the DOM directly when using React.

You need to have a "flag" that dictates if you want to render the extra component or not.

Something like

```
function ComponentA(){
  const [renderComponentB, setRenderComponentB] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRenderComponentB(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
     <div id="parent">
       {renderComponentB && <ComponentB/>}
     </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Although i am not sure why you want to delay the `ComponentB` for just one rendering cycle.

---

As far as the `getBoundingClientRect` of `ComponentA`, there is no such thing, as that depends on what the component actually renders in the DOM. `ComponentA` in it self is not part of the DOM.

In your specific case, though you could add a `ref` to the `#parent` element and use that for the `getBoundingClientRect`, since it is your "container" element of the `ComponentA`

```
function ComponentA(){
  const [renderComponentB, setRenderComponentB] = useState(false);
  const parentRef = useRef(); 

  useEffect(() => {
    setRenderComponentB(true);
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
     const rect = parentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
     // do what you want with the rect here
     // if you want to apply values to the ComponentB
     // add them to a state variable and use those when 
     // rendering the ComponentB
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
     <div id="parent" ref={parentRef}>
       {renderComponentB && <ComponentB/>}
     </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I want to load the `ComponentB` because the position of it depends on the `parent`. So, unless it is rendered, I am not sure I can find the position and size of the component. Please guide me if you have any solution to it.

Comment: Also, do you know how to get `ComponentA.getBoundingClientRect()` of the componentA?

Comment: @Sakaggi `ComponentA` is not a DOM element that can get queried for DOM properties. It depends on what you render in it. But you can add a `ref` to the `#parent` element and use that to get its bounding rect. Updated answer with some extra code

Comment: I have tried using `ref` but it gives an error ` TS2322: Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.`

Comment: I was able to solve it by using `const parentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);` instead of `const parentRef = useRef();`

Answer (score 3):

Try using `conditional rendering`, like below :

```
export default function ComponentA() {
  const [renderComponentB, setRenderComponentB] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    setRenderComponentB(true);
  }, []);
  return(<div id="parent">
    {renderComponentB && <ComponentB/>}
  </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call method that returns component in render.
You do not need useEffect as i understood from your answer.

```js
function ComponentA(){
 function AddComponentB(){
  return <><ComponentB /></>
 }
 return 
  <>
   <div id="parent">
    {AddComponentB()}
   </div>
  </>
}
```

Comment: I want to render `componentB` after the `componentA` has been rendered.

Comment: You are calling AddComponentB function at render function of ComponentA. So, it can not be rendered without rendering ComponentA.